# Unable to access a NodePort service on Minikube running on AWS

Tags: minikube

I've been fallowing the tutorial from the official Kubernetes website on an AWS instance for testing (ubuntu 20.04) after installing minikube:

```
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/
```

And I've exposed the nodeport - 31055 as mentioned below- from security group but I'm still unable to get access to the app remotely. When I try to use curl with the url to the app from ssh access to the remote server I can get the result that I'm looking for but I can't access it from the browser.
I tried to start minikube with docker driver and without a driver too, but I'm still facing the same issue. 
Any idea how can I solve this ?
Thanks

Below the full yaml of the service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-04-10T15:47:01Z"
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:spec:
        f:externalTrafficPolicy: {}
        f:ports:
          .: {}
          k:{"port":8080,"protocol":"TCP"}:
            .: {}
            f:port: {}
            f:protocol: {}
            f:targetPort: {}
        f:selector:
          .: {}
          f:run: {}
        f:sessionAffinity: {}
        f:type: {}
    manager: kubectl-expose
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-04-10T15:47:01Z"
  name: example-service
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "521"
  uid: e19ea9a3-9700-4e37-b810-defb7e4fee67
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.99.135.151
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.99.135.151
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 31055
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    run: load-balancer-example
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: What are the error messages in browser?

Comment: @Matt I got "Unable to connect

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ..."

Comment: What do you mean by `I tried to start minikube [...] without a driver`? Do you mean that you did not use a `--driver` flag or that you used `--driver=None`

Comment: @Matt I've tried the tutorial with --driver=docker and with --driver=none but in the two cases I had the same problem.

Comment: Start it with --driver=none and check with netstat or ss if the nodePort is open and listening on 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

So one solution is to install `conntrack`:

```bash
apt install conntrack
minikube start --driver=none
```

A much better solution is to start minikube the normal way, then do this (I've used all zeros here but you could get granular with your security as appropriate for your environment):

```bash
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 svc/<service-name> <external-port>:<service-port>
```

External port is the one exposed to the internet and service port is the one that the container is listening on. For example, if my service is named `badstore` and it is listening on port 80

```bash
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 svc/badstore 8888:80
```

Comment: While these commands may solve the problem, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why they do would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.